# iOS AVPlayer and WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, avplayer

So I currently have a UIWebView that contains video player controls such as Play/Pause/Volume/ect and an AVPlayer instance that is a subLayer of the view. Currently, the video overlaps the player ui which is fine currently because the video is smaller than the controls so they dont overlap.

However, I am trying to add a fullscreen mode, and an extended display mode.

My question is, how would I add the AVPlayer inside the UIWebView without overlapping the controls, so that I can set the video to fullscreen but also overlay the controls over the video when needed?

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had such a situation and I searched a lot. At the end I found two ways to do that.

1. Most nice way: Simply implement your code using [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953)

   ```
   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
   [player prepareToPlay];
   [player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
   [myView addSubview: player.view];
   // ...
   [player play];
   ```
2. If you really want to use UIWebView then think about embedded HTML5 `<video>` tag.

   `<video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>`

and load the HTMLString with the method

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

but personally I would prefer the first solution with autoplay enabled and you are getting your controls including for full-screen and AriPlay automatically.

Comment: The problem with using MPVideoPlayer is that it prevents access to AVFoundation which contains video metrics that I need to track. I was thinking there could be a way where I add the UIWebView as a sublayer over the video sublayer?

Comment: Why don't you use a UIView as a parent view instead UIWebView?

Comment: What would be the benefit?